# How to enable multiple databases of ServiceConnection type using testcontainer in a spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-testcontainers

I am using multipleDatasources in my spring boot application where we connect to postgres and mysql. it is working as expected but when I want to integrate it with TestContainers in dev mode . I have written code as below

```java
@TestConfiguration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class TestMultipleDataSourcesApplication {

    @ServiceConnection
    @Bean
    //@DependsOn("mySQLContainer")
    PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgreSQLContainer(DynamicPropertyRegistry dynamicPropertyRegistry) {
        PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgreSQLContainer =
                new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:16.0-alpine");
        dynamicPropertyRegistry.add("app.datasource.member.url", postgreSQLContainer::getJdbcUrl);
        dynamicPropertyRegistry.add(
                "app.datasource.member.username", postgreSQLContainer::getUsername);
        dynamicPropertyRegistry.add(
                "app.datasource.member.password", postgreSQLContainer::getPassword);
        return postgreSQLContainer;
    }

    @ServiceConnection
    @Bean
    MySQLContainer<?> mySQLContainer(DynamicPropertyRegistry dynamicPropertyRegistry) {
        MySQLContainer<?> mySQLContainer = new MySQLContainer<>("mysql:8.1");
        dynamicPropertyRegistry.add("app.datasource.cardholder.url", mySQLContainer::getJdbcUrl);
        dynamicPropertyRegistry.add(
                "app.datasource.cardholder.username", mySQLContainer::getUsername);
        dynamicPropertyRegistry.add(
                "app.datasource.cardholder.password", mySQLContainer::getPassword);
        return mySQLContainer;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.from(MultipleDataSourcesApplication::main)
                .with(TestMultipleDataSourcesApplication.class)
                .run(args);
    }
}
```

Only the postgresql Bean is getting started and mySQLContainer is getting discarded. to force start mySQLContainer I have added `@DependsOn("mySQLContainer")` on PostgreSQLContainer then it is getting started. My application uses flyway for connecting to mysql and liquibase for connecting to postgres as below

```
## Flyway uses mysql database
spring.flyway.url=${app.datasource.cardholder.url}
spring.flyway.user=${app.datasource.cardholder.username}
spring.flyway.password=${app.datasource.cardholder.password}

## Liquibase used postgres Database
spring.liquibase.url=${app.datasource.member.url}
spring.liquibase.user=${app.datasource.member.username}
spring.liquibase.password=${app.datasource.member.password}
```

When starting databases using above method, even my flyway is connecting to postgresqlserver instead of mysqlserver.

What is the correct way to start more than one database related ServiceConnection and how to ensure that after setting the urls it is connecting to correct liquibase or flyway instances?

source code : https://github.com/rajadilipkolli-throwaway/boot-data-multipledatasources

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to define a spring test profile specifiying jdbc url like `jdbc:tc:mysql:8.1:///cardholderdb`

So Testcontainer's JDBC driver would automatically start the mysql container without your definition in TestMultipleDataSourcesApplication. I'd suggest to do the same for postgres using the `jdbc:tc:postgresql:16.0-alpine:///memberdb`

see https://java.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/jdbc/ for more details

Comment: Unfortunately My code also needs these information for liquibase so it is not possible

Comment: Ah sorry, did not realize this. So indeed you cannot benefit by this approach. Had a quick look into your code. You are using SpringBoot 3.1. So checkout this link https://spring.io/blog/2023/06/23/improved-testcontainers-support-in-spring-boot-3-1
You could add the two containers directly to your ApplicationIntegrationTest class and init flyway/liquibase by a static void init method (more ore less what you alread have in your TestMultipleDataSourcesApplication class.  Thus, the latte will be obsolete.

Comment: I am trying to make it run as testcontainers in dev mode. Hence the issue, for Junits I have work around and it is working.